# Deserializing array in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON output that I need to deserialize into a .NET object:

```
{   "title": "Stock data",
    "raw_data": [
    [
      1088553600000,
      1.3635
    ],
    [
      1091232000000,
      1.3538
    ],
    [
      1093910400000,
      1.3563
    ]]
}
```

If I'm using JsonConvert, how should I structure my class such that the deserialization works?

Comment: What are the types in the "raw_data" that you're expecting? An int and a double, or are they both doubles? If they're different, they you may have a problem as the JSON is technically for "raw_data" is an array of arrays. Tho you could implement a custom serializer for your class and put it into anything you want.

Comment: Both doubles should work fine for me. I couldn't find an example on how to structure a class for an array of arrays. Do you have any hints on how I should declare the raw_data property?

Comment: Sure, I would think double[][] would work just fine, tho I haven't tried it.

Comment: Appreciate the help - I went with Reinard's suggestion and it worked. Your suggestions probably works as well.

Comment: Yep, it works too, just tried it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types for raw_data are both doubles then something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public List<List<double>> raw_data { get; set; }
}
```

Cool website you might want to check out: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my original answer was worthless, here's a better answer.

You probably ran into trouble because you saw those types as an integer and double value (natural for a C# programmer), however Json knows nothing of these types and represents numbers simply as decimals.

As another answer has said, you can simply deserialize as a list of lists of doubles. Interestingly, there is an option to convert it to a more natural representation.

However, I am not recommending this as it's not exactly typesafe when deserializing (The type of the original element is lost when converting to decimal, you can only suppose this way would work)!

```
public class BarArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // Not properly implemented!
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();

        // Read the first token after the start array
        reader.Read();

        // Parse elements of the array
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            Bar b = new Bar();

            // Convert these as necessary to your internal structure. Note that they are nullable types.
            b.First = reader.ReadAsDecimal();
            b.Second = reader.ReadAsDecimal();


            // Read end array for this element
            reader.Read();
            // Pull off next array in list, or end of list
            reader.Read();

            bars.Add(b);
        }

        return bars;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


class Bar
{
    public decimal? First;
    public decimal? Second;
}

class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(BarArrayConverter))]
    [JsonProperty("raw_data")]
    public List<Bar> RawData { get; set; }
}
```

It is almost certainly more sensible to use the decimal types. The only reason I can see to do this is if there were a requirement to leave the first value as an integer, this would be a way to restrict the value of the variable in a more natural way.